# Given a list of elements, replicate each element N times

Tags: prolog

I have to replicate each element n times like this:
**?- replicate([a,b,c],2,X).  -> X = [a,a,b,b,c,c]
?- replicate([a,b,c],3,X).  -> X = [a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c]**

I have tried everything with the information I have so far, the only thing I have been able to do is to determine which is the most repeating element like this:

```
%List of tuples, keeps track of the number of repetitions.
modify([],X,[(X,1)]).
modify([(X,Y)|Xs],X,[(X,K)|Xs]):- K is Y+1.
modify([(Z,Y)|Xs],X,[(Z,Y)|K]):- Z =\= X, modify(Xs,X,K).

highest((X1,Y1),(_,Y2),(X1,Y1)):- Y1 >= Y2.
highest((_,Y1),(X2,Y2),(X2,Y2)):- Y2 > Y1.

maxR([X],X).
maxR([X|Xs],K):- maxR(Xs,Z),highest(X,Z,K).

rep([],R,R).
rep([X|Xs],R,R1):-modify(R,X,R2),rep(Xs,R2,R1).

maxRepeated(X,R):- rep(X,[],K),maxR(K,R).


?- maxRepeated([1,3,3,4,3,2] ,X).
X = (3, 3) .

?- maxRepeated([1,2,3,4,5,6] ,X).
X = (1, 1) .
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do ? 
Take each element X of the list, get a list of N X and create a new list with the process of the rest of the list !
How to get a list of N elements X ?

```
replicate_one(X, N, Out) :-
    length(Out, N),
    maplist(=(X),Out).
```

Now, how to work with each element of the input, it can be easily done with the pattern [Head|Tail] :

```
replicate([Head|Tail], N, Out) :-
    % I replicate the rest of the list
    replicate(Tail, N, Tmp1),
    % I replicate the first element of the list
    replicate_one(Head, N, Tmp2),
    % I concatenate the 2 results
    append(Tmp2, Tmp1, Out).
```

When you work with **replicate**, the input looses an element each time, so you must have a process for the empty list :

```
replicate([], _N, []).
```

Now :

```
  ?- replicate([a,b,c],3,X).
X = [a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c].
```

Answer (score 0):

We can split the problem into two problems:

1. generate a list of `N` elements `X` with a predicate we implement `replicate_item/3`; and
2. do this for every element, and *concatenate* the result in a prdicate named `replicate/3`.

[@joel76](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56322054/67579) already provided a nice implementation for `replicate_item/3`. I will only change the order of the parameters:

```
replicate_item(N, X, List) :-
    length(List, N),
    maplist(=(X), List).
```

Now our `replicate/3` prdicate can iterate over the list, and for each element use `replicate_item/3` to generate a sublist. We can then use [**`append/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2) for this:

```
replicate(LA, N, List) :-
    maplist(replicate_item(N), LA, LL),
    append(LL, List).
```